# Custom Regressor to use with sklearn.AdaboostRegressor

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I want to provide my own custom regressor as a base_regressor input to sklearn.AdaboostRegressor constructor. What methods should my custom regressor class implement in order to work with sklearn.Adaboost

Answer (score 0):

You should inherit from `BaseEstimator` and `RegressorMixin` and implement `fit` (which **has to** support `sample_weight`) and `predict`.